# How to parse multiple files and put the output in generated dynamic file using awk?

Tags: awk

Here is my awk script `filtered.awk` which works fine for a single input file.

```
#Field Seperator
BEGIN { FS="[,:\"]" }

#Searching and Storing in an Array
/searchKeyword/ {a[$5]=a[$5]OFS$6}

#Looping on Array
END {
     for (k in a)
      {
        print FILENAME, k, gsub(OFS,OFS,a[k]) > ("output_" FILENAME)
      }
}
```

Sample input-

```
cat input1.txt
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc:06","200OK",64594889937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc:13","200OK",64594860937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc:06","200OK",64594822937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc:06","200OK",64594823937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:13","200OK",64594890937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:08","200OK",64594877937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:13","200OK",64594860937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:13","200OK",64594870937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde:12","200OK",64594803937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde:00","200OK",64594870937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde:00","200OK",64594860937362
"YY/XX","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde:08","200OK",64594825193736
```

second input file -

```
cat input2.txt
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr:99910","200OK",439865231,"4334373212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde:99904","200OK",439868231,"4334953212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno:99909","200OK",439827231,"4334178212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr:99911","200OK",439874231,"4334353212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde:99900","200OK",439893231,"4334130212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno:99910","200OK",439886231,"4334868212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr:99905","200OK",439850231,"4334495212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde:99905","200OK",439878231,"4334131212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno:99910","200OK",439871231,"4334895212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr:99910","200OK",439874231,"4334353212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde:99908","200OK",439848231,"4334823212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno:99914","200OK",439820231,"4334177212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr:99910","200OK",439882231,"4334579212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde:99903","200OK",439840231,"4334966212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno:99908","200OK",439894231,"4334365212"
```

third input file

```
cat input3.txt
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde:99900","200OK",439893231,"4334130212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno:99910","200OK",439886231,"4334868212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr:99905","200OK",439850231,"4334495212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde:99905","200OK",439878231,"4334131212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno:99910","200OK",439871231,"4334895212"
"XXX/YYY","searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr:99910","200OK",439874231,"4334353212"
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc:06","200OK",64594822937362
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc:06","200OK",64594823937362
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:13","200OK",64594890937362
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:08","200OK",64594877937362
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:13","200OK",64594860937362
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr:13","200OK",64594870937362
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde:12","200OK",64594803937362
"PPP/QQQ","searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde:00","200OK",64594870937362
```

I passed the input files like below and got the output in `output_input3.txt` file.

```
awk -f filtered.awk input*
cat output_input3.txt
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde 6
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde 7
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr 8
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr 7
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc 6
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno 7
```

looks like it is not processing the first two files at all.

And I was expecting output in dynamically generated files like below -

```
==> output_input1.txt <==
input1.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde 4
input1.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr 4
input1.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc 4

==> output_input2.txt <==
input2.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde 5
input2.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr 5
input2.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno 5

==> output_input3.txt <==
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde 2
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde 2
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr 4
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr 2
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc 2
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno 2
```

but I am getting output in only one file `output_input3.txt` Any suggestion ?
And how we can further divide the dynamic file generation for output like below -

```
==> output_input1_cde.txt <==
input1.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde 4

==> output_input1_pqr.txt <==
input1.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr 4

==> output_input1_abc.txt <==
input1.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc 4

==> output_input2_cde.txt <==
input2.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde 5

==> output_input2_pqr.txt <==
input2.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr 5

==> output_input2_mno.txt <==
input2.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno 5

==> output_input3_cde.txt <==
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde 2
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde 2

==> output_input3_pqr.txt <==
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr 4
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr 2

==> output_input3_abc.txt <==
input3.txt searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc 2

==> output_input3_mno.txt <==
input3.txt searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno 2
```

NOTE: I am using awk on mac (awk version 20070501) and tried with ENDFILE, I think ENDFILE doesn't exist in awk on mac.

Comment: I can't see what you are trying to achieve with that but `END` can only see the last instance of `FILENAME`. If you are using GNU awk, try replacing `END` with `ENDFILE` and see if that's what you want (you may need to `delete(a[k])`, maybe add `close`  but like I said, I don't understand what you are trying to do). Sample data with expected output usually helps a lot.

Comment: You're asking for help to parse multiple files but have provided just 1 file containing just 1 line as the example of the input you're trying to process. Think about whether or not that's truly/adequately representative of the real input you want to process.

Comment: @VIPIN KUMAR, Could you please check my solution if that worked for you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - I tried your solution but getting output in one file and for third input file only.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - I will request you to check the updated section of question   "expected output" and your code is behaving like my code in which first two files are not getting processed or not showing in output file.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR, , Kindly check my updated answer now and let me know then in comment section of my answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thanks for your effort and I tried your solution and got error -  `fatal: attempt to use scalar `a' as array`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR, it worked fine for me. Which version of `awk` do you have? This error sometime comes when `length` option is not present for arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`END` can only see the last instance of `FILENAME`. If you are using GNU awk, try replacing `END` with `ENDFILE` and see if that's what you want (you may need to `delete a`, maybe add `close`*. Using GNU awk (due to `ENDFILE`):

```
$ cat foo.awk
#Field Seperator
BEGIN { FS="[,:\"]" }

#Searching and Storing in an Array
/searchKeyword/ {a[$5]=a[$5]OFS$6}

#Looping on Array
ENDFILE {                                              # replaced END with ENDFILE
     out="output_" FILENAME                            # to define just once
     for (k in a) 
     {
         print FILENAME, k, gsub(OFS,OFS,a[k]) > out
     }
     delete a                                          # added delete
     close(out)                                        # good habit eventho GNU awk
}
```

Results:

```
$ cat output_input1 
input1 searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc 4
input1 searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde 4
input1 searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr 4
$ cat output_input2
input2 searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno 5
input2 searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde 5
input2 searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr 5
$ cat output_input3
input3 searchKeyword-ZZZZ.abc 2
input3 searchKeyword-YYYYY.mno 2
input3 searchKeyword-ZZZZ.cde 2
input3 searchKeyword-ZZZZ.pqr 4
input3 searchKeyword-YYYYY.pqr 2
input3 searchKeyword-YYYYY.cde 2
```

If you don't have GNU awk and `ENDFILE` available, you need to handle the `FILENAME` in `FNR==1` and the `END` blocks. Of course you could (and should) make a `function()` and call them from previously mentioned blocks but to highlight:

```
#Field Seperator
BEGIN { FS="[,:\"]" }

FNR==1 {
    if(filename!="") {                                  # no file before the first
        out="output_" filename                          # using previous filename
        for (k in a)
        {
            print filename, k, gsub(OFS,OFS,a[k]) > out
        }
        delete a                                        # empty env
        close(out)                                      # close used file
    }
    filename=FILENAME                                   # remember filename
}
#Searching and Storing in an Array
/searchKeyword/ {a[$5]=a[$5]OFS$6}

#Looping on Array
END {
     out="output_" FILENAME
     for (k in a)
     {
         print FILENAME, k, gsub(OFS,OFS,a[k]) > out
     }
     delete a                                        # good habit but more for
     close(out)                                      # symmetricity
}
```

**Update**: Updated as requested in the comments. Sorry, I missed that part totally at the first time.

```
#Field Seperator                                                                  
BEGIN { FS="[,:\"]" }

FNR==1 {
    if(filename!="") {                                # no file before the first  
        for (k in a)
        {
            n=split(k,f,".")                          # get the abc etc           
            out="output_" filename "_" f[n] ".txt"    # construct the filename    
            print filename, k, a[k] >> out            # appending to files        
            close(out)                                # spare the fds             
        }
        delete a                                      # empty env                 
    }
    filename=FILENAME                                 # remember filename         
}
#Searching and Storing in an Array                                                
/searchKeyword/ {a[$5]++}                             # changed the counting      

#Looping on Array                                                                 
END {
    for (k in a)
    {
        n=split(k,f,".")                              # etc                       
        out="output_" filename "_" f[n] ".txt"        # construct                 
        print filename, k, a[k] >> out                # append                    
        close(out)                                    # fds                       
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please suggest how to handle second part of the the question to create sub files based on the common string in the lines.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR Added a version. I changed the main block, I hope that's what you were after.